# AES encryption using same key generating different values in Java and PHP

Tags: java, php, security, aes, phpseclib

In PHP, I am unable to decrypt a string encrypted in java using AES CBC 128 bit. I have tried bott phpseclib and openssl on the PHP side. Though my preference is for phpseclib.

**Java Side**

1. I generated an AES 128 bit key using:

   ```
   keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
   keyGen.init(128);
   secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
   ```
2. Generated an initialization vector by getting bytes from a string:

   ```
   byte[] iv = "myuniqueivparam".getBytes("UTF-8");
   ```
3. Encrypted a string as follows:

   ```
   Cipher enCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
   ```

   // the key and iv are passed on to php as strings

**PHP side**

1. Set the algorithm:

   ```
   $aes = new Crypt_AES(CRYPT_AES_MODE_CBC);
   ```
2. The key and iv I got from java are passed as strings:

   ```
   $aes->setKey($userKey); 
   $aes->setKeyLength(128);
   // when I echo this I get myuniqueivparam
   $ivdecode=base64_decode($iv); 
   $aes->setIV($ivdecode);
   ```
3. Set the same input and add padding

   ```
   $input="winning";
   $blocksize = 16;
   $pad1=$blocksize -(strlen($input) %$blocksize);
   $input1=$input . str_repeat(chr($pad1), $pad1);
   ```
4. Encrypted the string using phpseclib:

   ```
   $aes = new Crypt_AES(CRYPT_AES_MODE_CBC);
   $dummy = base64_encode($aes->encrypt($input1));
   echo $dummy;
   ```
5. `$decryptedstring=$aes->decrypt($encryptedStringInJava);`

**Issues**

1. When I print `$dummy`, in step 4, the encrypted string that I get does not match the encrypted string from java.
2. Decrypting `$encryptedStringInJava` is not working in PHP (step 5)

I have tried encryption/decryption in java using both phpseclib and openssl.

Comment: Probably has something to do with the key and how it is encoded (you wouldn't be able to copy-paste it in its binary form, which is how PHP would expect it).

Comment: key is being passed as string and setKey function is being used to load it to instance of new Crypt_AES() $aes->setKey($userKey);

Comment: I can see that, but "as a string" means nothing here. The question is how (if at all) is it *encoded*. If you echo it and it looks like garbage - then it is raw binary and it likely got corrupted, because you can't just copy-paste binary as regular text. If it's hex, base64 or otherwise encoded - you need to pass the decoded version.

Comment: On another note, IVs are supposed to be random, not just unique; you should generate them in the same way you generate the keys.

Comment: this is how a key looks like when I issue echo EZi+iLi/yDYS84ZS2k49Qw== . also I plan to generate a random IV everytime.

Comment: Yea, I'm pretty sure you need to `base64_decode()` that before passing to `setKey()`.

Comment: ok will try and should I use any encoding for IV. its as string "myuniqueivparam"

Comment: Thanks Narf....base64_decode() did the trick. thanks a ton